# Java - HashMap Memory : optimization

Tags: java, memory, hashmap

I would like to know if there is a more efficient way of handling hash maps.

I have the following Map (primary) which is composed of its key and another Map as the value.

```
   final Map<String,Map<Boolean,String>> primaryMap = new HashMap<>();
     Map<Boolean,String> secondaryMap = new HashMap<>();
```

For each key I assign 2 secondaryMaps and I inititalize the secondary map again.The sequence is similar to the one displayed below:

```
 secondaryMap = new HashMap<>();
       secondaryMap.put(true, "A");
       primaryMap.put("DOG", listedMap);

        secondaryMap.put(false, "B");
        primaryMap.put("DOG", listedMap);

 secondaryMap = new HashMap<>();

        secondaryMap.put(true, "C");
        primaryMap.put("CAT", listedMap);

        secondaryMap.put(false, "D");
        primaryMap.put("CAT", listedMap);
```

Could it be that there is a more efficient way to do this?
Does `secondaryMap.clear()` have an impact in the memory before calling  `secondaryMap = new HashMap<>();`

Many thanks in advance,

Kat

Comment: Are `listedMap` and `secondaryMap` supposed to be the same thing?

Comment: For sure, you can at least only call primaryMap.put("DOG", listedMap) once (And same for "CAT")

Comment: Each inner map can have at most two elements. Can you simply use a pair of two references? You can add a pair of bools to the node if you'd like to distinguish between missing key and a key mapped to `null`.

Comment: `Map<Boolean, String> secondaryMap = primaryMap.computeIfAbsent("DOG", k -> new HashMap<>());` is a nicer way of having maps in maps - and if you want space efficiency you could also use a map of Strings, e.g. `map.put("DOG", "AB")` and then `.getOrDefault("DOG", "  ").charAt(boolValue ? 0 : 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In so far as the inner `Map` can only have two keys, you could replace it by a custom class :

```
final Map<String,Map<Boolean,String>> primaryMap = new HashMap<>();
```

could be :

```
final Map<String, Foo> map = new HashMap<>();
```

and you could populate it such as :

```
 map.put("DOG", new Foo("A", "B"));
```

where the`Foo` constructor could be :

```
public Foo(String valueForTrue, Sting valueForFalse){
   this.valueForTrue = valueForTrue;
   this.valueForFalse = valueForFalse;
}
```

**It will spare some memory (as much less objects will be required) but overall it will make your code much clearer.**

Of course if you may add the `String` value only  for the `true` of the `false` case you could favor factory over public constructor in `Foo` such as :

```
private Foo(){
}

public static Foo ofTrue(String valueForTrue){
   Foo foo = new Foo();
   foo.valueForTrue = valueForTrue;
   return foo;
}

public static Foo ofFalse(String valueForFalse){
   Foo foo = new Foo();
   foo.valueForFalse = valueForFalse;
   return foo;
}

public static Foo of(String valueForTrue, Sting valueForFalse){
   Foo foo = new Foo();
   foo.valueForTrue = valueForTrue;
   foo.valueForFalse = valueForFalse;
   return foo;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess in order to get the value it would work the same way: for example, map.get("CAT").get(true)

Comment: @Katherine99  You are welcome. You could but you could also skip the param with something like `map.get("CAT").getTrueValue();`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this tip!

Comment: @davidxxx unless there will be proof for this, I don't think that simply saying that it will take less space is actually accurate. And it might be me here, but I actually like the `Map<X, Map<Y,Z>>`, again, might be me being weird

Comment: @Eugene This way doesn't have the Map object and doesn't have the booleans either. How do you want that it consumes as much as the other way ? "might be me being weird". If you like error prone code, you are maybe not weird but special :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your code or just a copy/paste problem but it looks like you would be more efficient with:

```
 secondaryMap = new HashMap<>();
 secondaryMap.put(true, "A");
 secondaryMap.put(false, "B");
 primaryMap.put("DOG", secondaryMap);
```

And `secondaryMap.clear()` before your `new` will also clear the map you put in the primary - they are **the same object**.